# Is there possible to set a trusted TLS certificate in a local server?

Tags: android, ssl, https, tls1.2, jitsi

I'm trying to use jitsi server in a local server project. I have to connect a mobile app to it. Can I trust my HTTPS certificate in a local server?

Answer (score 0):

Send the crt file to the mobile device, you can install the certificate in the Android system, which works for me.